# How sort values inside the list()?

Tags: r

I have a list

```
list(`groupA_2024-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2024-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupA_2022-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2022-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupA_2021-09-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2021-09-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupA_2024-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2024-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupA_2023-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2023-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"))
```

Names have two part 1)before _ and 2) after _ . Before shows to which group (A or B) it corresponds to and second part shows the date. I want to sort this list in the following way 1)Group,2)Date. The necessary output is following:

```
list(`groupA_2021-09-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2021-09-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"),
     `groupA_2022-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2022-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupA_2023-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2023-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"),
     `groupA_2024-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2024-02-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupA_2024-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupA"), class = "colDef"), 
     `groupB_2024-04-01` = structure(list(name = "groupB"), class = "colDef") 
)
```

I tried it with simply order function, however, here should be something complicated.

Comment: Looks complicated. Why not use the date first and the group second. Also without hyphens. E.g. `sort(c('20210901_groupB', '20210901_groupA'))`. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)-principle.

Comment: Why do you keep this data structure? I would transform it into a proper ["tidy"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data.frame.

Comment: @Roland I use this structure to plot tables in `reactable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the names from the list, keep only the date part, change to `Date` class, `order` the dates and rearrange the list accordingly.

```
data <- data[order(as.Date(sub('.*_', '', names(data))))]
names(data)

# [1] "groupA_2021-09-01" "groupB_2021-09-01" "groupA_2022-04-01"
# [4] "groupB_2022-04-01" "groupA_2023-02-01" "groupB_2023-02-01"
# [7] "groupA_2024-02-01" "groupB_2024-02-01" "groupA_2024-04-01"
#[10] "groupB_2024-04-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `trimws` from `base R`

```
lst1 <- lst1[order(trimws(names(lst1), whitespace = ".*_"))]
```

checking the order

```
> names(lst1)
 [1] "groupA_2021-09-01" "groupB_2021-09-01" "groupA_2022-04-01" 
 [4] "groupB_2022-04-01" "groupA_2023-02-01" "groupB_2023-02-01"
 [7] "groupA_2024-02-01" "groupB_2024-02-01" "groupA_2024-04-01" 
 [10] "groupB_2024-04-01"
```